# Not able to access post-gres database through various functions other than main() in Javascript program

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, asynchronous

I'm trying to query a database in my JavaScript program. From what I can tell, I have successfully connected to the database. When I query it from within the main() function, I'm able to print out a table with the correct values. If, however, I try to query the database from another function and call that function from main, nothing is outputted. I'm hoping someone can tell me why that is occurring.

The code that prints out the information:

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database:"A4"
});

main();

async function main() {

    try{ 
        await client.connect()
        console.log("Connected successfully");

        const results = await client.query("SELECT * FROM Students");
        console.table(results.rows);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(`Something wrong happened ${ex}`);
    } finally {
        await client.end();
        console.log("Client disconnected successfully");
    }
}
```

And the code that doesn't is basically the same except the results query and the console.table are called from a different function, and that function is called within main:

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database:"A4"
});

main();

async function main() {

    try{ 
        await client.connect()
        console.log("Connected successfully");

        getAllStudents(client);

    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(`Something wrong happened ${ex}`);
    } finally {
        await client.end();
        console.log("Client disconnected successfully");
    }
}

async function getAllStudents(client) {

    try {
        const results = await client.query("SELECT * FROM Students");
        console.log(results.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error executing query: ". error);
    }

}
```

I have looked into the client variable to make sure it does exist and is connected when I'm querying it. Ive checked it prior to connecting, after connecting, and from within the getAllStudents function and it seems to be the same in the last 2 scenarios, and just disconnected prior to connection.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated